# Incrementing Makefile Variable When Executing Rule

Tags: makefile

My dilemma is the following: I need to create a symbolic link to a different serial port for each of the items in the Makefile variable 'LINKS'. I have the following code.

```
LINK_PATH = ~/some/path/
LINKS = $(LINK_PATH)/SomeLinkName $(LINK_PATH)/AnotherLinkName $(LINK_PATH)/TheseLinkNamesUnchangeable    
COUNT = 0    

install: $(LINKS)
    #Do other stuff

$(LINKS): $(LINK_PATH)
    ln -s /dev/ttyS$(COUNT) $@

$(LINK_PATH):
    mkdir -p $@
```

I know that, as it is now, it will just create a bunch of links pointing to /dev/ttyS0. But I need them to be different, preferably sequential. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do the names of the links correspond to the `ttyS#` they should link to?

Comment: No. They are independent of each other. And I apologize, I will edit my question to make that more clear.

Comment: Then there isn't an easy way to do what you want assuming you want to keep the makefile set up like this (with each link as an independent make target). You *can* do it with eval and some magic like what the [GMSL](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) has if you really want though.

Comment: I did look into that briefly, but I just wanted to ensure that I wasn't missing any easier way to do this. I appreciate the direction @EtanReisner .

Comment: If the order of the `$(LINKS)` to `ttyS#` targets doesn't matter then there are games you could play in the recipe to make this work (walk to the next unlinked `ttyS#` entry or whatever before linking, etc.).

Comment: Alternatively you could use target-specific variables and some `$(eval)` magic to encode the link pairs in a variable and then create the target-specific variables and use those variables in the common recipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all of the serial ports are defined ahead of time, you can enumerate them and store that list in another variable then use that variable as a target dependency:

```
LINKS=/path/to/bar /path/to/baz /path/to/woz
COUNTS=$(shell v=`echo $(LINKS) | wc -w`; echo `seq 0 $$(expr $$v - 1)`)

install: $(COUNTS)

$(COUNTS):
    @echo ln -s /dev/ttyS$@ $(shell v=($(LINKS)); echo $${v[$@]})
```

then, when run:

```
[user@host: ~]$ make install
ln -s /dev/ttyS0 /path/to/bar
ln -s /dev/ttyS1 /path/to/baz
ln -s /dev/ttyS2 /path/to/woz
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much!